The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -1073741819
Why I got on this error when I want to run the python code in VScode? it's a new issue in my vscode it was work without any issue. any help please?
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -1073741819.

